# Recombination frequency

Tags: genetics

From Campbell Biology 2017, unit 15, test your understanding question 5:

Using the information from problem 4, scientists do a further testcross using a heterozygote for height and nose morphology. The offspring are tall upturned snout, 40; dwarf upturned snout, 9; dwarf downturned snout, 42; tall downturned snout, 9. Calculate the recombination frequency from these data.

Why is the correct answer 18% and not 22%? My reasoning is that you should do a 9 + 9 = 18 and 40 + 42 = 82, and then do an 18/42 = 22%.

Comment: If you post this sort of question, like any other question, it must be self-contained. This question refers to a problem in a text book, so is only comprehensible to someone with that text. Hence it is off-topic here and I have voted to close. Please take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help on asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/asking) before posting again.

Answer (score 0):

For recombination frequency you have to consider the whole population of the offspring (not just the offspring that got not recombinated), means 40 + 42 + 9 + 9 = 100. Then you have 18 recombinants, and your recombination frequency goes with 18/100 = 18%.